# delta method with higher order terms to improve variance estimation accuracy

Tags: variance, delta-method

I need to apply the delta method principle using a Taylor expansion that retains higher order terms (i.e. to second or third order) in order to improve the accuracy of variance estimation.  The literature on the higher order delta method seems to focus on the special case where the first order term is zero leaving only a second order terms.  In contrast, I would like to retain all terms for the purpose of improving estimation accuracy.  Does anyone know of or has derived a delta method equation that includes higher order terms?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sure, you just take the Taylor expansion out to more terms. I don't think I understand the difficulty here - usually it's just tedious, not difficult.

Comment: As I am interested only in estimating variance and not the limiting distribution, I suppose that you are right.  The determination of higher order terms will be complicated by the ‘squaring’ of the Taylor series in the equation for variance, but the process is more tedious than difficult, as you say.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not even as tedious as all that:

$g(\mu+X-\mu) = g(\mu)+(X-\mu)g'(\mu)+(X-\mu)^2/2 g''(\mu)+(X-\mu)^3/3 g'''(\mu)+...$

\begin{eqnarray}\text{Var}(g(\mu+X-\mu)) &=& \text{Var}((X-\mu)g'(\mu))+\text{Var}(\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2} g''(\mu))\\& &+2\text{Cov}((X-\mu)g'(\mu),\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2} g''(\mu))\\& &+\text{Var}(\frac{(X-\mu)^3}{3!} g'''(\mu))\\& &+2\text{Cov}((X-\mu)g'(\mu),\frac{(X-\mu)^3}{3!} g'''(\mu))\\& &+2\text{Cov}(\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2}g''(\mu),\frac{(X-\mu)^3}{3!} g'''(\mu))+...\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}              &=& g'(\mu)^2\text{Var}(X)
                            \\& &+2g'(\mu)\frac{g''(\mu)}{2}\text{E}((X-\mu)^3 )
                            \\& &+\frac{g''(\mu)^2}{4}\text{E}((X-\mu)^4)
                            \\& &+2g'(\mu)\frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}\text{Cov}((X-\mu),(X-\mu)^3 )
                            \\& &+2\frac{g''(\mu)}{2} \frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}\text{Cov}((X-\mu)^2,(X-\mu)^3)
                            \\& &+(\frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!})^2\text{Var}((X-\mu)^3 )
+...\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}              &=& g'(\mu)^2\,\text{Var}(X)
                            \\& &+2g'(\mu)\frac{g''(\mu)}{2}\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^3 )
                            \\& &+[\frac{g''(\mu)^2}{4}+2g'(\mu)\frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}]\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^4)
                            \\& &+[2g'(\mu) \frac{g^{(4)}(\mu)}{4!}+2\frac{g''(\mu)}{2} \frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}]\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^5)
+...\end{eqnarray}

... and so on

Then you just make sure that at whatever point you stop, say to terms in  $(X-\mu)^k$, you have all the terms to that order.

Comment: I have not checked the algebra in detail, but your derivation looks correct – thank you.  In general, there are two approaches for evaluating a delta method expansion of variance.  One approach (different from yours) is to Taylor expand $g(X)$ in the expression, $Var[g(X)] = E[g(X)-E[g(X)])^{2}]$.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that the Taylor series must be squared which leads to a bit more algebra, and as well, an additional Taylor expansion must be done for the $E[g(X)]$ term.  The advantage of this approach is that the resulting expression contains only expectations (i.e. the various central moments of the random variable $X$) which are generally available.

Comment: The second approach is to evaluate the expression $Var[g(X)] = Var[g(\mu+X-\mu)]$ which you have done.  The disadvantage of this approach is that the resulting expression contains complex terms such as the variance and covariance of various powers and combination of powers of $(X-\mu)$.  In using this approach in practice, how would you propose that a user estimate the covariance of various powers and combination of powers of $(X-\mu)$ for example?

Comment: The basic idea is just to use some of the standard results for expectations or covariances. E.g. $\text{Cov}[(X-\mu)^m,(X-\mu)^n]=\text{E}[(X-\mu)^{m+n}]-E[(X-\mu)^m]E[(X-\mu)^n]$. I may have not done that correctly above, I need to double check.