# Second order with Delta method on a ratio to improve variance estimation accuracy

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, delta-method

Following a previous post on math exchange without success, I have applied the **"Delta method"** that says :

**Delta method :**

There are alternative formulations of this expression which may be more convenient to implement in some instances. When the variables $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} \ldots \theta_{k}$ (in the function, $\left.Y\right)$ are independent, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(\hat{Y}) & \approx \operatorname{var}\left(f\left(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \ldots \theta_{k}\right)\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \operatorname{var}\left(\theta_{i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{i}}\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\partial f / \partial \theta_{1}$ is the partial derivative of $Y$ with respect to $\theta_{i} .$ When the variables $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} \ldots \theta_{k}$ (in the function, $Y)$ are not independent, then the covariance structure among the variables must be accounted for:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(\hat{Y}) & \approx \operatorname{var}\left(f\left(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \ldots \theta_{k}\right)\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \operatorname{var}\left(\theta_{i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{i}}\right)^{2}+2 \sum_{i<j}^{k} \sum_{i} \operatorname{cov}\left(\theta_{i}, \theta_{j}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{i}}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{j}}\right)\quad(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

If I apply the second formula, I have the following expression for the variance of the ratio $b_f=\dfrac{b_1}{b_2}$ :

$$\text{Var}(b_f)=\dfrac{\sigma_1^2}{b_2^2}+\dfrac{\sigma_2^2\,b_1^2}{b_2^4} - 2\dfrac{b_1}{b_2^3}\,\rho_{\text{corr}}\sigma_1\sigma_2\quad(2)$$

But the value of Var(b$_f$) got with this $eq(1)$ is not suitable for other computations after (I think the error on variance is too large). The expression of Variance used for first order is :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(\hat{Y}) & \approx \operatorname{var}\left(f\left(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \ldots \theta_{k}\right)\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \operatorname{var}\left(\theta_{i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{i}}\right)^{2}+2 \sum_{i<j}^{k} \sum_{i} \operatorname{cov}\left(\theta_{i}, \theta_{j}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{i}}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{j}}\right)\quad(3)
\end{aligned}
$$

I need really accuracy on this computation of variance.

That's why I would like to get the expression of ratio variance of 2 random variables.

I found an interesting post [delta method with higher order terms to improve variance estimation accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90287/delta-method-with-higher-order-terms-to-improve-variance-estimation-accuracy)

The expression given goes up to 3 order. I want right now to limit myself up to 2 second order.

Here is the expression of this link :

$g(\mu+X-\mu) = g(\mu)+(X-\mu)g'(\mu)+(X-\mu)^2/2 g''(\mu)+(X-\mu)^3/3 g'''(\mu)+...$

\begin{eqnarray}   \text{Var}(g(\mu+X-\mu))           &=& g'(\mu)^2\,\text{Var}(X)
                            \\& &+2g'(\mu)\frac{g''(\mu)}{2}\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^3 )
                            \\& &+[\frac{g''(\mu)^2}{4}+2g'(\mu)\frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}]\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^4)
                            \\& &+[2g'(\mu) \frac{g^{(4)}(\mu)}{4!}+2\frac{g''(\mu)}{2} \frac{g'''(\mu)}{3!}]\,\text{E}((X-\mu)^5)
+...\quad(4)\end{eqnarray}

I would like finally to have this equation $eq(2)$ but for the ratio $b_f=\dfrac{b_1}{b_2}$ and for only second order.

**EDIT1 :** I realized that $g$ function is dependent of $b_1$ and $b_2$ so I have to expand Taylor of 2 variables, implying partial derivatives towards $b_1$ and $b_2$.

**EDIT2 :** I have found the expression for a Taylor expansion up to second order for 2 variables $x$ and $y$ :

$$
f(x,y)=f(a, b)+f_{x}(a, b)(x-a)+f_{y}(a, b)(y-b)+\frac{f_{x x}(a, b)}{2}(x-a)^{2}+f_{x y}(a, b)(x-a)(y-b)+\frac{f_{y y}(a, b)}{2}(y-b)^{2}\quad(5)
$$

with $f_x$, $f_y$ the partial derivatives and $f_{xx}$, $f_{yy}$ the double partial derivatives.

There are common points with the expression (3) of just 1 order but I don't know to manage the covariance terms. How to compute the variance of this expression $\text{Var(f(x,y))}$ ?

I need some support to perform it, if someone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: I don't understand why I got a downvote, is it really justified ?

Comment: No it's not justified, particularly without some kind of constructive comment. This post shows research effort, so I have upvoted. +1

Comment: @microhaus . Thanks, it is kind from your part.